# looping checkboxes not equal to zero in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-ui, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes with class `checkbox_item`.I need to loop through all checkboxes which are not checked and their second part of splitted `#ID` value ,
ie `$('.checkbox_item').prop('id').split('_')[1]` should not be equal to zero

```
<input class="checkbox_item" id="414_0.5" type="checkbox">test
<input class="checkbox_item" id="415_1" type="checkbox">test1
<input class="checkbox_item" id="416_0.5" type="checkbox">test2
<input class="checkbox_item" id="417_0" type="checkbox">test3
```

My jquery function is as following:

```
 $('.checkbox_item').not(':checked').each(function(index,elem){
   /here I dont need checkboxes whose splitted #ID [1] not equals to zero
});
```

I have google it and couldn't find anything positive.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood your question correctly, as you pretty much had the answer already. Nonetheless, hopefully the below helps:

```js
$('.checkbox_item').not(':checked').each(function(index,elem){
    var id = $(this).prop('id').split('_')[1];

    // Use `!=` instead of `!==` to allow type coercion to occur, in order to compare with `0`
    if (id != 0) {
        console.log(id);
        // Manipulate current DOM element using jQuery `$(this)`
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox_item" id="414_0.5" type="checkbox">test
<input class="checkbox_item" id="415_1" type="checkbox">test1
<input class="checkbox_item" id="416_0.5" type="checkbox">test2
<input class="checkbox_item" id="417_0" type="checkbox">test3
```